# Writing data to mySQL database from form submission

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write the data in a form submission to mySQL, however it will not appear in my database.

I am learning programming so please forgive me if I have not provided enough information.

The data in the form submission is the users email and password when they sign up.

Below is the code for the sign up form:

```
<!--This is for the Modal sign up-->
      <h2>Sign Up Form</h2>
      <form id="signupFormJS" class="SignUpFormCSS" method="post">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="emailCSS" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="passwordCSS" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
        </div>
          <button class="SubmitButtonCSS" id="SubmitButtonJS" type="submit">SignUp</button>
```

Here is the code from the python file to write the data to the mySQL database:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def signup():
   SignUpForm1 = SignUpFormStructure()
   if SignUpForm1.validate_on_submit():
      email = request.form.get['email']
      password = request.form.get['password']
      username = None  # Assuming you're intentionally setting this to None
        db.session.add(record)
        db.session.commit()
      SQL_Location = "INSERT INTO user (password, username, email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
      cursor.execute(SQL_Location, (hashed_password, username, email))
      db.commit()
```

I have been able to write data from python to my database so I am satisfied I am using the correct path, port etc. However when I try to write data from a form, it does not work.

In summary, I am using HTML, JavaScript, Python (with flask forms and SQL alchemy)

I have tried the above and I was expecting the data to write to the database however this does not work.

Comment: The indentation of the code is wrong,  it wouldn't run.